# Codeigniter CIUNIT

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

In regards with Codeigniter PHP Unit which is CIUNIT, created by kenji from this topic http://d.hatena.ne.jp/Kenji_s/20120117/1326763908. Is there any way to simulate session variable?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the PHP sessions variable, you can set it anywhere in your code:

```
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
```

If you're talking about the CodeIgniter session variable from the [Session class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html), you can also set the values dynamically:

```
get_instance()->session->userdata['foo'] = 'bar';
```

You have to do that in your tests methods, before doing the test.